# Please help me find error - program which shows prime numbers

Tags: c

I am learning C , could you help me find the error in my program? 
I retyped code from the book and still I don't know where is my mistake.
I tried to use https://www.diffchecker.com/diff but I don't see any logical difference. I give up.
Could you help me?

My code:

```
//ex7_9.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void){

    int num;
    int limit;
    int div;
    bool isPrime;

    printf("Please insert your number: ");
    while((scanf("%d", &limit) == 1) && limit > 0){
        if(limit > 1)
            printf("Here are prime numbers up to %d limit\n", limit);
        else
            printf("Change limit - to bigger than one\n");

        for(num=2; num <= limit; num++){
            for(div=2, isPrime=true; (div*div) <=num; div++){

                if(num % div ==0)
                    isPrime = false;

                if(isPrime)
                    printf("%d is prime \n",num);

            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

proper code:

```
//ex7_9.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void){

    int limit;
    int num;
    int div;
    bool numIsPrime;

    printf("Enter a positive integer: ");
    while (scanf("%d", &limit) == 1 && limit > 0){
        if (limit > 1)
            printf("Here are the prime numbers up through %d\n", limit);
        else
            printf("No primes.\n");
        for (num = 2; num <= limit; num++)
        {
            for (div = 2, numIsPrime = true; (div * div) <= num; div++)
                if (num % div == 0)
                    numIsPrime = false;
            if (numIsPrime)
                printf("%d is prime.\n", num);
        }
        printf("Enter a positive integer (q to quit): ");
    }
    printf("Done!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

results from my code:

```
Please insert your number: 10
Here are prime numbers up to 10 limit
5 is prime 
7 is prime 
9 is prime
```

Comment: What is the error you see?

Comment: I don't see proper results, it ommits 2 and 3 :(

Comment: Your problem is the curly brackets of the last `for`. It's only meant to loop around the next `if`, not the last one. (`if(isPrime)` should be outside of the `for` scope)

Comment: Your issue is adding a set of {} that aren't in the original. `for (div = 2, numIsPrime = true; (div * div) <= num; div++)` just calls the first `if(num %div ==0)` and not the second print for is prime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You added brackets on your inner loop.

Your code is

```
for(num=2; num <= limit; num++){
    for(div=2, isPrime = true; div * div <=num; div++){
        if(num % div == 0)
        {
            isPrime = false;
        }
        if(isPrime)
        {
            printf("%d is prime \n",num);
        }
    }
}
```

while the original with explicit brackets added is

```
for (num = 2; num <= limit; num++)
{
    for (div = 2, numIsPrime = true; div * div <= num; div++)
    {
        if (num % div == 0)
        {
            numIsPrime = false;
        }
    }
    if (numIsPrime)
    {
        printf("%d is prime.\n", num);
    }
}
```

Your second `if` is inside the inner loop; in the original it is outside.